# Why is image capture with opencv so dark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

When I open my webcam for video stream, the image is way more clearer then if I take a shot using open cv, as showed below. Why does this happen? How can I get clearer images from opencv, without changing the exposition?

```
def take_pic(cam_id : int, image_name : str):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_id)
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    cap.release()
    if ret:  # if got an image
        gray_version = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imwrite(image_name, frame)
```

Comment: *how* do you open your "webcam for video stream"?

Comment: I don't see a dark picture.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz opening the capture device in VLC

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the image was darker because I was getting the first frame after open camera for video capture; discarding the first 3-15 frames solved it